# Functional Analysis Question: Extreme Points

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that every boundary point of $S=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \|x\|_2 \leq 1\}$ is an extreme point.

I've started this by choosing $w,z \in S$ such that they are boundary points. And I am trying to show that the norm of their midpoint is less than 1. But every time I do the calculation I get the norm to $\leq 1$. I'm supposed to use a result from inner products to show this but I'm a bit lost.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know when you have equality in the triangle inequality?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: $\|\frac{w+z}{2}\|_2 \leq \frac{1}{2}(\|w\|_2+\|z\|_2) = 1$

Comment: When do you have $\lVert w+z\rVert = \lVert w\rVert + \lVert z\rVert$? In all other cases, you have a strict inequality, and then you need to see that for the sphere, you can't have equality.

Comment: When either w or z equal 0?

Comment: Yes, but those aren't all cases.

Comment: So When $w=1-z$?

Comment: Don't guess. Take a fixed $w\neq 0$. For which $z$ do you have $\lVert w+z\rVert = \lVert w\rVert + \lVert z\rVert$? Draw a picture, that helps.

Comment: Well if i draw it w,z must essentially be the same vector (different scales) but the triangle would have to be made up of 180 degrees and 2 0 degrees... Think I'm on the wrong lines with this...

Comment: "essentially be the same vector (different scales)" Hopefully that means "$z$ must be a non-negative multiple of $w$". You have equality in the triangle inequality if and only if (at least) one of the vectors is $0$, or the two are positive multiples of each other. Now, if you take two different vectors from the sphere $S$, can they be positive multiples of each other?

Comment: No. So this means that it must be strictly less than 1.

Comment: Sorry that seemed quite painful for me to understand! Thanks very much for your help!